# Using a specific font by @font-face

Tags: html, css, font-face

my problem is, I want to use a specific font type called (Daniel) which is not supported by google fonts, so I have used (@font-face) and it worked but only for the home page but the other pages which at the site are not working and I can not figure out the reason!
Would you help me please to solve this problem?

P.S
This problem is shown only at Mozilla firefox browser and mobile phones, google chrome is going well!

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Daniel';
src: url('Daniel.eot');
src: url('Daniel.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('Daniel.woff') format('woff'),
     url('Daniel.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('Daniel.svg#Daniel') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

and here is the the problem shown at firefox console:[image]

Comment: Maybe try to download this font and add it to a specific folder in your website folder, like "FONTS/Daniel.ttf" or whatever, because the issue seems to be a network issue..

Comment: What kind of url is that font in? Did you download the font and put it on your own server?

Comment: of course I do, and it works well at google chrome, this problem only at firefox and mobile phones and only for the other pages not the  home page

Answer (score 0):

Download font file and then place it somewhere in you project directory and use it like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Steiner Light';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Steiner Light'), url('../fonts/Steinerlight.woff') format('woff');
}

.body{

  font-family: 'Steiner Light' !important;
  font-size: 20px !important;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: $orange;

}
```

Comment: I did just what you said, and it worked for the home page, this problem is at the other linked pages !

Comment: but I didn't try ! important , I will try it

Comment: I think you are overriding font in other pages